# Customized error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I achieve that the code below only will be executed if there is an HTML input-Tag? So that it won't be executed by the HTML label-Tag.

```
<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe
```

Thanks in advance!

Regards
Silvan

Comment: Is this using the dynamic_form gem/plugin? You need to expand on your question to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you're asking what I think you are you could do something like:

```
<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe unless html_tag.nil?
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, could you please explain more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the prompt answer.
I'll have the div-field_with_errors only around the input tags and not also on the label tags. With your solution it happens on both tags.
Is it now in more detail what I want to achieve?
Thanks & Regards